# Deleted databases before detaching

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I was trying to delete some websites on my machine and also deleted the database files before detaching them from SQL server. now when I try to open up my database tree in SSMS, I get an error Stating 'Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)'

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Unable to open the physical file "`C:\<Folderpath>\<DatabaseName>.mdf`". Operating system error 3: "3(The system cannot find the path specified.)". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)

How do I resolve this? I don't need the old databases back but I do need access to the other databases I still have, they're not being displayed in SSMS.

I've tried reattaching the databases I need but the error I get is:

> Attach database failed for Server for "'\SQLEXPRESS'
>
> **Additional information:**
>
> Cannot attach a database with the same name as an existing database

Thanks

Comment: Is there some reason you can't detach the old database from SSMS?

Comment: My databases aren't showing up in object explorer any more, but trying to reattach them gives me the second error

Comment: Can you run `EXEC master.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'MISSING_DB_NAME'`?

Comment: Awesome, that's done it, I've reattached the DB after doing this Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'll change that to an answer then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `EXEC master.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'MISSING_DB_NAME'` to manually detach the database.  You should then be able to reattach the DB from SSMS normally with the old name.